# Can I cross the border from Vietnam to China with a motorcycle?

Tags: china, vietnam, motorcycles

Last year, I spent one month in Vietnam. I know it is very easy to buy a used motorcycle there. Crossing the border to Cambodia is very difficult. I met people who made it into Cambodia with their motorcycles coming through Laos. I don’t know anybody who went into China with their motorcycle.

Has anybody been able to cross the border of Vietnam into China with a motorcycle registered in Vietnam?

Comment: Do you intend to return with said motorcycle to Vietnam? Related reads, maybe dupes: [What documents are required to drive a motorcycle from Kazakhstan to China?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/60757/32134) and [How can one get a permit to drive the Chinese section of Karakoram Highway with a foreign truck?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/73979/32134)

Comment: See also https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/asia-south-east-asia-mainland/vietnam/is-it-possible-to-cross-the-border-from-vietnam-to-china-on-a-motorbike and https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/asia-north-east-asia/china/laos-china-border-crossing-whit-a-vietnamese-motorbike as well as https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/asia-north-east-asia/china/china-on-a-motorbike?page=2

Comment: I start in Hanoi and drive to Chengdu along the Tibetan border. I would be surprised if the bike would make it till Chengdu:). If I still have the motorcycle in Chengdu, I’m going to sell it. I will buy the motorcycle in Hanoi. That means it is registered in Vietnam. I don’t care if I can register the Motorcycle in China or not. I just worried about the border crossing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No.

As I have written in [What documents are required to drive a motorcycle from Kazakhstan to China?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/60757/32134) you need a guide and plenty of paperwork to get a vehicle into China. Much of this paperwork is to ensure you don't import the vehicle but that it leaves China again after your trip. This does not change for a motorcycle as in [What documents are required to drive a motorcycle from Kazakhstan to China?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/60757/32134)

For a throw-away bike as you intend that is not worth the trouble, as we are talking thousands of USD here. Also abandoning the bike in China would not go well with the authorities upon your exit from the country.

[Plenty](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/asia-south-east-asia-mainland/vietnam/is-it-possible-to-cross-the-border-from-vietnam-to-china-on-a-motorbike) of [trip](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/asia-north-east-asia/china/laos-china-border-crossing-whit-a-vietnamese-motorbike) reports on the [LP forum](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/asia-north-east-asia/china/china-on-a-motorbike?page=2) confirm this.

Comment: It's interesting that China, the world's biggest automaker, is so strict about importing vehicles.